# Insert Excel data to sql database having error

Tags: c#, sql, excel, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert the data in to sql from an excel sheet.
My excel sheet containing details are

```
Product Id            Youtube Url

23345566               www.example.com
2514                   www.example.com
```

the code is working correctly.but when the product id is big(more tha 4 numbers)it will inserted like  2.33456e+007.means the second id inserted correctly,but the first id inserted like like 2.33456e+007.Anyone know what is the problem??

Comment: But some times the Product id having character values......

Comment: change the **`Product Id` datatype** to **varchar(100)**

Comment: Your C++ code is picking numbers, use `.Text` to pick strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format your excel column Product ID as Text.

Comment: Or as Number without decimal places!